# Updating Xamarin Forms causes System.IO.FileNotFoundException - ReactiveUI.Winforms when using ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget, reactiveui

After updating the Xamarin Forms package in my project to 3.4.0.1009999 I have started getting a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` when using `WhenAnyValue` from the `ReactiveUI` package. The API instructions only say to include `ReactiveUI`, `ReactiveUI.XamForms` and `ReactiveUI.Events.XamForms` which I have.

Despite this I get **Could not load file or assembly 'ReactiveUI.Winforms' or one of its dependencies** here:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.DiscountSliderValue).Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800)).Subscribe(CartManager.Instance.UpdateDiscountPercent);
```

Adding in the `ReactiveUI.Winforms` package sadly does not help.

This is code and packaging that has been working in this project for 6 months or more with no issues so it is a new problem. I have spent a significant amount of time looking for answers and have found nothing.

Any ideas on the cause?

Comment: What version of ReactiveUI are you using?

I just loaded a brand new project with
Xamarin.Forms 3.4.0.1009999 and ReactiveUI 9.7.2

Comment: Are you sure some package does not accidentally reference `ReactiveUI.Winforms`? There is no reason the library could want it, because it has and can have no relationship to `Xamforms`. Windows.Forms is a completely different technology stack. Could you search your whole solution folder contents for "Winforms" to make sure there is no forgotten or accidental link

Comment: My ReactiveUI packages are all 9.7.2 and also Xam Forms 3.4.0.1009999 as well. Doing a project wide file search shows only the Nuget reference in the csproj file.

Answer (score 5):

I have run into the same issue but the other way round. Winforms is asking for the XamForms dll, when nothing should be referencing XamForms

Checking the fusion log shows that in my case the calling assembly is ReactiveUI, *see trimmed version below:*

> === Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: DisplayName = ReactiveUI.XamForms, Version=9.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>   Calling assembly : ReactiveUI, Version=9.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

Which doesnt make any sense to me!

The solution that I found was to close Visual Studio and delete the whole .vs folder.
Sometimes the information in that folder becomes corrupt. I cant say for sure why or even if this was the real cause because it doesnt seem like it should be, but it seemed to work for me.